# How to choose an object from a set of objects based on max of particular method in python

Tags: python

I have a class like this!

```
import numpy as np
class blocks():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = np.random.rand()
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value
```

Now, I create a set of objects,

```
my_set= set()
for _ in range(20): my_set.add(blocks())
```

I want to choose the object with has a max value using the get_value() output

**what I have tried:**

```
my_list=list(my_set)

my_list[np.argmax([b.get_value() for b in my_set])]
```

It solves my problem, but not in a efficient manner. I cannot change the first step, which is creating some other datatype instead of set.

Looking for some better ways to do the same!

Thanks.

Comment: `max(my_list,key=lambda item:item.get_value())`

Comment: This will reduce overhead to an extend, but I dont want to typecast to list at first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` works just as well with sets. You can use a `key` parameter to call the `get_value` function. I've used `operator.methodcaller` to circumvent the lambda call for better performance.

```
import operator

f = operator.methodcaller('get_value')
max(my_set, key=f)
# <__main__.blocks at 0x1217e0630>
```

Answer (score 1):

max() function works with anything that is iterable. Python set() is iterable, so something like this should work for your example:

```
max(my_set, key = lambda block: block.get_value())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

# Assuming you have some container for the objects
# mycont
max_obj = reduce(lambda _b1,_b2: _b1 if np.greater(_b1.get_value(), _b2.get_value()) else _b2, mycont)

# print(max(list(map(lambda x: x.get_value(), mycont)))) # checkme
```

Comment: Hi @Doom, Thanks for your help. I tried your answer but `operator.methodcaller` was performing better in terms of performance. Hence am not accepting this answer.